# Is there any tool that can test a potential XFS superblock for validity?

Tags: filesystems, xfs, superblock

All XFS superblocks start with `XFSB`. Given a list of potential superblocks, is there any method to test them for validity?

```
$ sudo grep --byte-offset XFSB -ao /dev/sdb
689569283:XFSB
1114071063:XFSB
22922251552:XFSB
23758178652:XFSB
```